# An Error in swift when I tried to run a code

Tags: swift

I'm trying to learn swift language. I have downloaded it for windows 10. Unfortunately, when I tried to run the hello world code (test code), the compiler could not find the file in the workspace even it could not find the workspace folder it self!!!. I tried to change the name of the work-space since it contains a space "My Programs". But, the compiler rejected this change. I have posted with this question some pictures which describe my problem. Any help with this is highly appreciated.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I think that it's not happy with space in between "My" and "Programs". To fix this rename the folder to "My-Programs" and then select the file and again and retry with the new path.

Comment: Thank you @torinpitchers for your answer. Unfortunately I have tried this solution before and the swift engine asked me to use the default workspace  which "My Programs". So, do you have any other solution? many thanks in advance.